# Error: does not name a type (c++)

Tags: c++, list, pointers, object

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to create a linked list that uses a `LinkedList` and `Node` class. In the `List` class, how do I create the `head`, `curr` and `temp` objects? I thought I could just initialise them as objects, which would then call the default `Node()` constructor and assign them a data and pointer variable. But I am getting the error: `‘Node’ does not name a type` and `‘head’ was not declared in this scope` for the objects `head`, `curr` and `temp`. 
Here's my code:

LinkedList.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;

LinkedList::LinkedList() { 
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;

    cout << "Blank list created." << endl;
}

LinkedList::LinkedList(value_type addData) {
    Node n(addData);
}
```

LinkedList.h:

```
class LinkedList {
    public:
        typedef std::string value_type;

        LinkedList();
        LinkedList(value_type addData);

    private:        
        Node head;
        Node curr;
        Node temp;
};
```

Node.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;

Node::Node() {
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = NULL;

}

Node::Node(value_type addData) {
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = addData;

}
```

Node.h:

```
class Node {
    public:
        typedef std::string value_type;

        Node();
        Node(value_type addData);
    private:
        struct node {
            value_type data;
            node* next;
        };

        typedef struct node* nodePtr;

};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks guys!

Comment: Add `#include "Node.h"` to `LinkedList.h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what the compiler does with `LinkedList.c`. It starts with this:

```
...
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "Node.h"
...
```

Then it evaluates the `#include` directives, and pulls `LinkedList.h` and `Node.h` into the source:

```
...
class LinkedList {
...
  Node head;
  Node curr;
  Node temp;
};

class Node {
...
};
```

Then it tries to compile this, gets as far as "Node head;" (when it has not yet reached the declaration of the class `Node`), and complains that it doesn't know what you're talking about.

The file that declares `class LinkedList` needs to know what a `Node` is. Put `#include "Node.h"` near the top of `LinkedList.h` (and add header guards to `Node.h`) and you won't have this problem.

Comment: Ahh okay. Well I tried that and just received a bunch more errors: [link](http://i.imgur.com/mlRDT1g.png) that I have no clue what they refer to. And I have header guards, was just trying to condense the post so I didn't include them.

Comment: @Lachie: You wrote a lot of code without testing any of it, then you solved the problem that stopped the compiler at the top of the file; now the compiler can go past that point and scream about a lot of other errors. I think the best way to proceed from here is to either simplify the code until there are no errors or just start over from scratch, then reintroduce complexity slowly, testing at every step, and **never add to code that doesn't work.** (P.S. you have no idea what these error messages refer to? Google can help, as can Stack Overflow.)